# es6 react webpack import Home from './Home' when './Home' is a folder

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

If I understand it correctly, with `resolve: {extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']}` webpack setup, the following statement

`import Home from './Home'`

will look for `'./Home.js'`, `'./Home.jsx'`, `'./Home/index.js'`, `'./Home/index.jsx'`

My questions is, in addition to above 4 files, how can I teach webpack to also look for `'./Home/Home.js'`, `'./Home/Home.jsx'` using the same import statement.

Comment: Why do you want to use the same statement instead of `import Home from './Home/Home'` when you need it ?

Comment: @Pcriulan really just curious, I would imagine there is a way of doing it because the folder name and the file name is the same. It would also help structuring my folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your resolve, you need to specify a root path like so:

```
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('.'),
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js'],
  }
```

This tells webpack to begin at the root of directory.